# How to create a .deb that deals with different init systems

Tags: systemd, sysvinit, deb

I'm learning how to create a .deb file using jdeb in order to deliver a maven based java headless application inside debian based distributions.

It needs to be installed in such a way it auto start at boot time.

In the examples that I found in web jdeb is being set with a data directory containing a init.d file.

```
 <data>
     <src>${project.basedir}/src/deb/init.d/</src>
     <type>directory</type>
     <mapper>
         <type>perm</type>
         <prefix>/etc/init.d</prefix>
         <filemode>755</filemode>
         <user>root</user>
         <group>root</group>
     </mapper>
   </data>
```

But how can I deal with different init systems? should I set a data tag for systemd, sysvinit and upstart all together?

thank for any insight.

Answer (score 2):

There is no magic in such a case. You can't use a Debian package's static copy to install both the systemd and sysV files because this will duplicate services.

So, the solution I found was to deliver the configuration files as normal files inside the deb file, and then to implement a routine inside the postinst / postrm scripts that identifies which init system the target machine is running and then copy the right file to the proper directory.

```
if [[ `systemctl` =~ -\.mount ]] 
then 
  cp $serviceDir/service-systemd /lib/systemd/system/$serviceName.service
elif [[ -f /etc/init.d/cron && ! -h /etc/init.d/cron ]]
then 
cp $serviceDir/service-sysvinit /etc/init.d/$serviceName
fi
```

Comment: Thanks Cristiano for your own feedback, is it possible to gist your files somewhere. I am interested in also because I am developing for Raspberry. ;-)

Comment: @Thomas, I left the company where I needed to do this, but I will search in my backups soon... Let you know if I found them...